# Unity Mouse getaxis issue

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a script that just essentially rotates the x and the y axis of a camera.

```
void Update () {
    float xRot = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X");
    float yRot = Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y");

    Vector3 rotate = new Vector3(xRot, yRot);

    transform.Rotate(rotate);

}
```

It appears as the input from the Mouse X is the actually the Mouse Y and vice versa.  I know I can fix the problem just by flipping the xRot and the yRot in the assignment of the Vecort3 variable. So I was wondering if there is a better way to get the x and y axis of the mouse or if I just accidentally modified my project some how. Also would appreciate it to know how to fix the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a problem, just how things are.

Left and right are the horizontal axis. Your first thought would be assign them to the x value. Problem is that the rotation rotates around the given axis and most likely left/right should be rotating the object towards the left or the right.

But to do so, you can think of a pole (like a pole dancer) and you'd be rotating around it. If you are real close to it, it'd be like rotating left-right. But this axis is going up, and it is the up vector.

It means that to rotate left-right, you rotate around the up vector but use the left-right buttons which are the horizontal axis.

Obviously, if you want to rotate so that you can look down-up, you will rotate around the right (x) axis and use the vertical movement.

To conclude, there is no more simple or more logic solution than inverting the input. You could change the input setting so that horizontal is vertical and vice-versa but I would not recommend it.

Answer (score 0):

```
var pos = Input.mousePosition;
var x = pos.x;
var y = pos.y;
```

The bottom-left of the screen or window is at (0, 0). The top-right of the screen or window is at (Screen.width, Screen.height).